# Extract Name from an HTML page using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, regex, post, jquery-selectors

My University provides grade card, that is really very confusing and calculating final result is really very tough. Because all subjects has different weightage for final.

I am developing a BCA result calculator. Here is this https://www.bobdn.com/IGNOU_BCA_Result.aspx

I have following code in a div (I can't change it because it is returned from the University website)

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META NAME="GENERATOR" Content="Microsoft Visual Studio 6.0">
<TITLE>Grade Card</TITLE>
<h1> Grade Card </h1>
<h1>&nbsp;</h1>
(All programs Except for BIT/ADIT)

</HEAD>
<BODY  bgcolor=Lavender>


<form name=FRMResult method=post action=Result.asp>
<center> <font size=+2> Indira Gandhi National Open University </font>
 <br> Grade Card Status as on May 09, 2012<br> (For information only)</center>
 Enrolment Number: 092853268<br> Name: SHASHWAT TRIPATHI<br> Program: BCA<p><font size=-1> The Status is indicative only & cannot be used as a substitute for the final grade card which is sent by SRE at the end of a semester.</font><br><table border=1 width='80%' background='ignou.gif'><tr><td width='10%'>  Course Code </td><td width='10%' align=center>  Asgn1 </td><td width='10%' align=center>  Asgn2 </td><td  width='10%' align=center>  Asgn3 </td><td  width='10%' align=center>  Asgn4 </td><td  width='10%'>  Term End Theory </td><td  width='10%'>  Term End Practical</td><td width='10%'>  Status </td></tr><tr><td width='5%' >BCS61</td><td width='10%' >80</td><td width='10%' >73</td><td width='10%' >-</td><td width='10%' >-</td><td width='10%' >40</td><td width='10%' >67</td><td width='20%' >Completed</td></tr><tr><td width='5%' >BSHF1</td><td width='10%' >35</td><td width='10%' >35</td><td width='10%' >-</td><td width='10%' >-</td><td width='10%' >41</td><td width='10%'>-</td><td width='20%' >Completed</td></tr><tr><td width='5%' >CS5</td><td width='10%' >80</td><td width='10%' >87</td><td width='10%' >-</td><td width='10%' >-</td><td width='10%' >48</td><td width='10%'>-</td><td width='20%' >Completed</td></tr><tr><td width='5%' >CS6</td><td width='10%' >70</td><td width='10%' >67</td><td width='10%' >-</td><td width='10%' >-</td><td width='10%' >59</td><td width='10%'>-</td><td width='20%' >Completed</td></tr><tr><td width='5%' >CS60</td><td width='10%' >90</td><td width='10%' >87</td><td width='10%' >-</td><td width='10%' >-</td><td width='10%' >53</td><td width='10%'>-</td><td width='20%' >Completed</td></tr><tr><td width='5%' >CS610</td><td width='10%' >60</td><td width='10%' >60</td><td width='10%' >-</td><td width='10%' >-</td><td width='10%' >48</td><td width='10%'>-</td><td width='20%' >Completed</td></tr><tr><td width='5%' >CS611</td><td width='10%' >80</td><td width='10%' >80</td><td width='10%' >-</td><td width='10%' >-</td><td width='10%' >52</td><td width='10%' >88</td><td width='20%' >Completed</td></tr><tr><td width='5%' >CS612</td><td width='10%' >70</td><td width='10%' >67</td><td width='10%' >-</td><td width='10%' >-</td><td width='10%' >70</td><td width='10%'>-</td><td width='20%' >Completed</td></tr><tr><td width='5%' >CS62</td><td width='10%' >80</td><td width='10%' >80</td><td width='10%' >-</td><td width='10%' >-</td><td width='10%' >40</td><td width='10%' >91</td><td width='20%' >Completed</td></tr><tr><td width='5%' >CS63</td><td width='10%' >90</td><td width='10%' >93</td><td width='10%' >-</td><td width='10%' >-</td><td width='10%' >48</td><td width='10%' >85</td><td width='20%' >Completed</td></tr><tr><td width='5%' >CS64</td><td width='10%' >59</td><td width='10%' >59</td><td width='10%' >-</td><td width='10%' >-</td><td width='10%' >40</td><td width='10%'>-</td><td width='20%' >Completed</td></tr><tr><td width='5%' >CS65</td><td width='10%' >50</td><td width='10%' >53</td><td width='10%' >-</td><td width='10%' >-</td><td width='10%' >-</td><td width='10%' >97</td><td width='20%' >Completed</td></tr><tr><td width='5%' >CS66</td><td width='10%' >80</td><td width='10%' >80</td><td width='10%' >-</td><td width='10%' >-</td><td width='10%' >57</td><td width='10%'>-</td><td width='20%' >Completed</td></tr><tr><td width='5%' >CS67</td><td width='10%' >83</td><td width='10%' >83</td><td width='10%' >-</td><td width='10%' >-</td><td width='10%' >-</td><td width='10%' >93</td><td width='20%' >Completed</td></tr><tr><td width='5%' >CS68</td><td width='10%' >63</td><td width='10%' >63</td><td width='10%' >-</td><td width='10%' >-</td><td width='10%' >62</td><td width='10%' >77</td><td width='20%' >Completed</td></tr><tr><td width='5%' >CS70</td><td width='10%' >70</td><td width='10%' >67</td><td width='10%' >-</td><td width='10%' >-</td><td width='10%' >45</td><td width='10%'>-</td><td width='20%' >Completed</td></tr><tr><td width='5%' >CS71</td><td width='10%' >90</td><td width='10%' >87</td><td width='10%' >-</td><td width='10%' >-</td><td width='10%' >-</td><td width='10%'>-</td><td width='20%' >Not Completed</td></tr><tr><td width='5%' >FST1</td><td width='10%' >66</td><td width='10%' >66</td><td width='10%' >-</td><td width='10%' >-</td><td width='10%' >73</td><td width='10%'>-</td><td width='20%' >Completed</td></tr></table><br/><font size=-1 >Not with standing the result published/declared, any case of UFM(Unfairmeans) if found will make such result null and void.</font><p>&nbsp;</p><u>Note:- Assignment 4 and TE Practical do not apply to all the courses.</u><font size=-1 color=blue><center>Disclaimer: This electronically generated information does not have any legal validity</font></center>
<P>&nbsp;</P>



<a href="javascript:history.back()">Back </a>

<!--#'include file=scroll.js-->

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Suppose I put this code in a div with ID `tempDiv`
**Now how can I extract student's Name and Program from the `tempDiv`**

Also, here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bsBCR/4/) that shows the relevant part of the HTML from the University.

Comment: So what is the question? You did a great job providing plenty of background and that's awesome, but can you **edit** the question and on the bottom just clarify again in a sentence or two what the problem is? Thanks, and welcome to SO!  **Consider showing your code and where you think the problem is. Making everyone go through all the links is kinda confusing.**

Comment: I did make my questions bold @jmort253 please help in extracting student's Name and Program

Comment: Does it make sense to you that there are just too many links for us to reasonably know where exactly your problem is? While it's great that you know this like the back of your hand, keep in mind you're asking volunteers, who have only heard about your project for about 5 minutes, to help you with a problem, so please please post the code in the question that you think contains the problem. This will help give us some context regarding the problem and also help you get better, faster answers. :)  Good luck!

Comment: @jmort253 Sorry for all that. Now I edited my question completely. Hope this can help you helping me.

Comment: Much much better :) Will take a look. Thanks!  +1

Comment: I edited your post to more easily show the name. If it's buried in the HTML like that, you'll likely need an HTML parser of some sort. I'm going to leave this for someone more familiar with ASP.NET than me to answer. Editing your question bumped it to the top of the front page so other users should see it, and it looks a LOT better now. Good luck finding your answer :)

Comment: @jmort253 Thanks For your editing it is more clear now. But ur edit has an issue. Look on the line after code. It is written `Back` it should not here. I tried removing this but can't

Comment: Fixed. Also, I made you a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bsBCR/1/) for you and other users to play around with to work with the relevant HTML. You may need to use a regular expression to target the content you're wanting to retrieve from this, since it's not wrapped in a nice DOM element. Retagging your question as regex so other users see. Please check the jFiddle and if it's not right you can rollback my edit to your question. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work:

```
function getNameProgram(){

   var strTotal=document.getElementById('tempDiv').innerHTML;
   var ind1=strTotal.indexOf('Name');
   var ind2=strTotal.indexOf('Program');
   var ind3=strTotal.indexOf('<P><FONT size=-1>');
   var strName=strTotal.substring(ind1,ind2);
   var strProgram=strTotal.substring(ind2,ind3);
   strName=$.trim(strName.replace('Name:','').replace('<BR>',''));
   strProgram=$.trim(strProgram.replace('Program:',''));

   alert('MYNAME:'+ strName + '\n' + 'MYPROGRAM:' + strProgram  );

}
```

Comment: Hi CodeRoller, I made you a http://jsfiddle.net/jrQqY/2/ so you can see the results, make some edits, and debug this thing. It's not 100% working correctly at the moment, but with a few more edits I think you can get it there. Your ind1 value looks like it makes sense, but check your trim calls as I think that's where it might be going wrong. :) Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much jmort. I actually tested it without the jquery and just put it there lol. I will try to edit the fiddle to make it worj with the trims. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: @CoderRoller Please edit this fiddle and make it work http://jsfiddle.net/jrQqY/9/

Comment: Check that jsfiddle now and let me know :)

Comment: @CodeRoller Thanks a lot. I used ur solution with very few optimization. here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jrQqY/34/

Comment: Fantastic!. Interesting optimization. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your html will remain the same... you can use the following code

```
var z = $('form').html();    //grab the html
var za = z.split('<br>',4);  //split using <br> tags
var name = za[3];            //the element which has the name

var purename = name.replace('Name: ','');  //replace 'Name: ' with space to get pure name
alert(purename);​ //alert it
```

In case the IGNOU changes the html u will have to edit it again.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/lonewolfs/bsBCR/5/)

Comment: u r ryt. If IGNOU changes the format I have to make changes accordingly. My this whole project is dependent on the mark up. I made it my way https://www.bobdn.com/IGNOU_BCA_Result.aspx

Comment: Gz! hope you got your answer though :)

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes that you've already retrieved the HTML from the remote server and have loaded it on your HTML page. Once on your page and in the context of the DOM, the following code will retrieve the name from the HTML:

```
var form = $('form').text();
var nameIndex = form.indexOf("Name: ");
//alert(i);
alert(form.substring(134 + 5));   // prints the name
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/bsBCR/2/ for a demo.

One word of caution, many systems have API's that you can use to retrieve data more easily from the system. An API is like a contract between your application and the third-party application where you both promise that you'll use the same URL to retrieve the data if the third-party promises to not change the "method signature" of that URL.

When retrieving and parsing RAW HTML, there is no contract. In plain English, if the University changes the structure of that HTML, your application will break. Be prepared to add that as a risk and to come up with a strategy to resolve that issue should that be necessary in the future.